# Mongoose populate where

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, where-clause, populate

I have two models - M1 and M2.

In M1 I have an array of M2 objects.

I'm trying to create a query that will grab a bunch of M1 models but ONLY if a certain field in M2 matches the criteria I set.

I've setup the models correctly (so M1 has an array of Schema.Types.ObjectId for M2).

Ideally I'd want to do something like this:

```
    var result = await M1.find({
        'm2.title': 'title-match',
        // ...
        // Plus other criteria
    })
    .populate('m2')
    .exec();
```

So what I would want back is all the M1 models that have an M2 model which have 'title' set to 'title-match'.

But this doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure why.

I've tried using 'match' in the populate function but this doesn't play nice with the other find criteria I setup (so for example I could include match in the populate function but if I have a M1 model that has the correct M2 models but it doesn't meet the other criteria then it gets left out).

I need all my populate filtering to be mixed in with the other filters so it correctly evaluates if it should include it in the results or not.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it's not possible to do. More info on this https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4043

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to do what you're trying to do. The code sample in your question doesn't work as you are expecting because M1 has no knowledge of `m2.title`. M1 only knows about its array of M2 ObjectId's.

You're going to have to query for all M1 documents that match your M1 criteria and populate M2:

```
const results = await M1.find({
  // ... m1 criteria
}).populate('m2').exec()
```

Then filter out all of the results that match your m2 title afterwards:

```
const finalResults = results.filter(({ m2 }) => m2.title === 'title-match')
```